# Can someone explain to me why the fringes would move apart in this air wedge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics, interference

> Consider two identical microscope slides in air illuminate by monochromatic light as shown below. A pattern of interference fringes is formed. If the wedge angle gets smaller, the fringes move further apart.
>
> [image]

I know that the air in between the two slides acts as a "thin film," but my teacher did not do a good job at explaining any more than that.